# Dropzone js dragging from outlook into browser not working in IE but works in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, dropzone

I'm using dropzonejs, I've created a simple drop zone for users to drag and drop external files into the browser window which are then auto uploaded to the site.

All works as expected however the user wants to drag and drop an email directly from outlook on to the drop zone for the site to then upload the .msg file. This works in chrome as the browser receives the file from outlook. However in IE it does not seem to work but saving the .msg to disk then dragging on from there works.

Its working in chrome and edge but IE11 seems to just ignore the file drop.

Comment: was this fixed? I'm having a similar issue, but it's from a seperate app that is not a physical file. It does not even work in Chrome. That being said, this is not a dropzone.js issue. It is an issue with finding the file that's not physically present. Any ideas?

Comment: No unfortunately. I managed to work around it getting users to use chrome for the file upload. I believe after a lot of searching i found it was a bug where outlook gives the wrong event to IE but chrome detects the error and fixes it.